# can i run the terminal in the background from applescript

Tags: applescript

I have an applescript that calls the terminal to run some functions every time my mac wakes up from a sleep. I am getting a bit annoyed of the terminal constantly popping up everytime I open up the laptop. is there a way i can set it so that the terminal can run in the background or in a minimised window and not keep popping up?

```
My AppleScript is as follows:
set desktop_folder to "$HOME/Desktop"
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script "cd desktop;cd project34;python3 main.py"
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this by itself, with out the **Terminal** *block*:

```
do shell script "cd ~/Desktop/project34; python3 main.py"
```

Note that you may need to include the *path* to `python3`.

Comment: @kitchen800, Did this work of you? If yes, I'd appreciate the answer been marked as the accepted answer if you feel it best answers your question, thanks.